# How can I add app client metadata in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant

I am totally new in AWS Cognito, but our goal is to create an API GW endpoint for tenants to upload their data to s3 bucket with a tenant directory prefix in a safe way (every tenant have a separate folder). Username - password login provided by Cognito's userpool is not the way what you should consider in case of machine-machine communication.

As far as I know AWS Cognito is a safe way to generate an app client with a client id and secret that we can give it to our customers and secure our endpoint. We need to add tenant_id or name metadata to that client to know what directory we should put their data in. The issue is that client is not part of the userpool itself and we cannot add any data to it in Cognito. U

Can we use the client_id itself? Should we handle this metadata-client_id relationship by ourselves? (store in a DB)
Or is it the cleanest approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that you can have a separate `S3` bucket for each tenant that comes with many benefits like custom object lifecycle policies per tenant, custom billing metrics with AWS based on bucket level usage etc.

In your Provider (Metadata) Database, where you store the tenant information, you can have the bucket details in the settings for a given tenant. So when a tenant uploads an image, you figure out the bucket and then use the AWS V4 header signature to upload to S3.

Please do share your thoughts on this idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Custom Scopes**

Not sure if it's cleanest approach.
I'm sure people are using scopes to provide access level, but custom scope can also be used to add metadata info. Essentially you can add `tenant_id` as a custom scope.

Access tokens contain scopes, so when it is presented to your secure endpoint the appropriate directory can be determine based on the provided `tenant_id` in the scope.

More info on creating Custom Scopes- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers.html

Comment: Using Custom Scopes to add metadata to Client App does work. However one would need to create a Resource Server separately for each App Client, to be able to define Custom Scopes for each Client App separately. Because Custom Scope is not a key-value, it's just a key. This might not be an issue at all, but in my case it was, because there are N App Clients, and Custom Scope is used for fine-grade authorization on my app-level. Maintaining also N Resource Servers would require extra effort, would require automation. Easier to just read App Client's ID and get it's metadata from DynamoDB table.

Comment: Yeah, you might be right there @tnurmi.